# Поиск по коллекции mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Нужно реализовать поиск в коллекции по массиву данных

Вот пробую через консоль такую команду

```
db.pages.find({ alias:{ $in:["page_alias", "page_alias2"] } });
```

Все работает прекрасно и возвращает результат, но когда пробую через обертку mongoose

```
 Page.find({ alias:{ $in:['vasya_alias', 'vasya_alias2'] }}, function (err, pages) {
    console.log(arguments);
});
```

то ничего не приходит, даже не могу попасть в callback запроса, вот схема модели

```
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

 var schema = new Schema({
   name:{
      type:String,
      required:true
  },
   alias:{
      type:String,
      required:true
  },

  description:{
      type:String
  }
 });
```

Comment: Скажите, сработает ли этот запрос с измененным критерием: 1) `{}`, 2) `{alias:{$exists:true}}`. Хочу понять, проблема в самом запросе или в его окружении)

Answer (score 1):

С [monoosejs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/index.html) :

`Kitten.find({ name: /^Fluff/ }, callback);`

This performs a search for all documents with a name property that begins with "Fluff" and returns the result as an array of kittens to the callback.

Единственное без понятия что из себя представляет объект callback - может там не функцию надо впиливать.

а вообще может стоит сюда глянуть.[Mongoose queries](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/queries.html)

Comment: Подозреваю, ему нужно искать точное совпадение с любым из списка элементов, а не похожесть. Неизвестно присхождение алиасов

Comment: @MiKeBu , ну я баловался с метеором - что-то схожее определенно есть, и там вторым аргументом в `find` был объект `{}`, который содержал в себе не критерии по которым значения фильтровались, а всякие `limit, skip` и подобные. Так кто я просто не уверен что вторым аргументом тут надо вставлять функцию..

Comment: `Model.find(conditions, [projection], [options], [callback])` - как видите, [тут](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.find) много опциональных параметров